# Query about DSE search

Tags: java, php, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

In order for my data to become searchable in solr which key space should I use for all of my Cassandra tables?

I have the following keyspaces after starting solr:

```
        system_traces
        solr_admin
        system
        dse_system
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use any of those keyspaces for creating your own tables. You need to create your own keyspace, then create your table in that keyspace and then create a solr core on the keyspace on the table.

How you do this will depend on the version of DataStax Enterprise you are running. On 4.8 you can to this through `dsetool` with the following command:

```
dsetool create_core keyspace.table generateResources=true reindex=true
```

You will then be able to perform search queries against that table.

[Here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchOverview.html) is the current search documentation for Solr search on DataStax Enterprise.

Comment: ok just one more question is it really necessary to use the solrconfig.xml and schema.xml for indexing everytime or can i get away with just using the CQL table?

Comment: with the solr integration you aren't querying the cassandra table but the solr core that is created from the cassandra table using the solrconfig and the schema. As such to need to either provide those or have dsetool generate them for you when the core is created.